# YiiReport crashes without explanation

Tags: yii, phpexcel, yii-extensions

I'm working in a webpage using the Yii Framework (http://www.yiiframework.com) and its YiiReport extension used to generate Excel files. I've been using this extension for some weeks and it works perfectly. However, I've uploaded some files to the online version of the web and now the online version, when trying to use the YiiReport, doesn't work (however, the local version works perfectly). I think I haven't changed anything directly relating the YiiReport extension, so I can't explain why it isn't working. The code relating the extension is really simple:

```
$r = new YiiReport(array('template'=> $template));

$r->load(array(
    array(
        'id' => 'ong',
        'data' => array(
            'name' => $nom
        )
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>$id,
        'repeat'=>true,
        'data'=>$data,
        'minRows'=>2
    )
  )
);

echo $r->render('excel5', $filename);
```

The webpage crashes as if the PHP document where the code is isn't found or is inaccessible. The problem relates to the last line of code: if this line is commented, the page doesn't crash (of course it doesn't generate the Excel file, but at least it doesn't crash); if a simple string is printed through the echo, the string is shown in the screen... The problem seems to come specifically from the "$r->render()" function, but I don't understand why. I think the extension is correctly located, because the page doesn't crashes when accesses the previous extension's functions, but I can't find what can be happening, and I've been working on it for a couple of days...

Any idea on what can be happening?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that your online version of PHP doesn't have as much memory as your dev server. I've seen weird errors with Excel generators and they generally seem related to memory constraints.

Comment: Hmmm makes sense... How can I check if this is actually the problem? And how could I solve it? Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: @Johanovski I'd start by seeing if exporting less data fixes your problem.  If it does, then that's a good indicator its memory related.  How many relations do you export and/or how many lines are you exporting at once?

Comment: I've tried exporting a single line without even connecting to the database but the problem persists, so I gues it isn't related to memory issues... The same file works perfectly on localhost but crashes when uploaded on the online web. Firefox complains that it was unable to find the file; however, when running the same file with the last line commented, the file is accessed and shown as expected (though, of course, no Excel is generated)... Chrome doesn't even say a thing! I really have no clue about this... Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Oh! And the PHP error log doesn't show anything related... :(

Comment: @johanovski you might try downloading a Php Excel extension (there is one for exporting CGridView tables) and see if that works. If it does, you should be able to copy the code they are using ...